# Is there a noticeable difference in weight between different brands of multifilament strings?

Tags: tennis, equipment

I recently got the strings changed on my *Head Gravity Tour*. Now it is noticeably more **head heavy**. To the point where it feels like a sledgehammer instead of its usual scalpel-like precision.

It had a set of *Head Rip Control* on it before the change, and now has *Babolat Xcel*.

Is there a noticeable difference in weight between these two strings?

I know there is noticeable difference between string types i.e. multifilament, poly, gut, but what about between the same type?

Comment: Head Rip Control 16/1.3 and Babolat Xcel 16/1.30 weigh _exactly the same_, do you have the same weight? or is one 16 and the other 17?

Comment: They are both 17s. Did you weigh them yourself by chance? I'm curious to know the specifics. I just weighed the *HEAD Rip Controls* and they came in at 15.4g. I haven't got another set of *Babolat Xcel* yet, but I Hear most Multifilaments are around 20g. The rip controls are made by means of " polyolefin ribbon construction". Maybe this is the reason they seem lighter? Anyway, I'll try to weigh a set of the Xcels, if the store lets me, and get back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally went to the local tennis shop today and weighed the two sets of strings. On their scale, the *Babolat Xcel* strings, at .17 gauge  weighed 20g, while the .17 gauge *Head Rip Control*s weighed 16g. I guess there can be a noticeable difference in weight between multifilament strings.